# Confusing NODE_MODULE error

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules

I am using the greenworks SDK. I don't understand this error message. I can't tell if it's telling me to recompile the greenworks-osx64.node or change my system node settings.

```
ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173 Uncaught Error: The module '/Users/quantum/ele/electron-quick-start/lib/greenworks-osx64.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 53. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or`npm install`).
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/quantum/ele/electron-quick-start/greenworks.js:12:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/quantum/ele/electron-quick-start/greenworks.js:133:3)
```

I am using electron ~1.6.2 and node -v v8.6.0

I missed there were other releases further down the page. I installed the one for electron 1.6.1. Now my code runs this:

var greenworks = require('./greenworks'); var f = greenworks.initAPI(); document.write(f); console.log(f);

"false" logged into the console.

Answer (score 0):

> The native Node modules are supported by Electron, but since Electron is very likely to use a different V8 version from the Node binary installed in your system, you have to manually specify the location of Electron's headers when building native modules.

Source: [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md)

Comment: What is `electron-gyp`?

Comment: The compiler of electron, the same as `node-gyp`, used to compile native module (written in C language) .

Comment: I recommend this [guide](https://blog.risingstack.com/writing-native-node-js-modules/)

Comment: Thanks - so you're saying I need to recompile greenworks manually with electron-gyp?

Comment: Yes, in the guide you cam find three way to do this.

Comment: And recompile it for 53 or 57? The error message confuses me as to which version is needed

Comment: If you use electron-rebuilt I don't need to worry about!